# Picking up an audio file android

Tags: android

I need to fetch an audio file from SD Card and play it. I think this can be done by getting URI of an audio file. So, to pick an audio file I'm using following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("audio/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Audio "), reqCode);
```

Now, I can browse for audio files and select one of them.

**QUESTION:** How to read the URI of picked file in my onActivityResult?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can put below codes in your project when you want to select audio.

```
Intent intent_upload = new Intent();
intent_upload.setType("audio/*");
intent_upload.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(intent_upload,1);
```

And override onActivityResult in the same Activity, as below

```
@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){

  if(requestCode == 1){

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        //the selected audio.
        Uri uri = data.getData(); 
    }
  }
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: according to me more easy way is:   
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent,1);

instead using intent_upload.setType("audio/*"); and rest of the part are fine.
thanks

Answer (score 6):

First of all, open the default Android file picker through an intent:

```java
public void openGalleryForAudio() {
    Intent videoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(videoIntent, "Select Audio"), AUDIO_REQUEST);
}
```

Then, using `onActivityResult`, you should catch the data.

```java
if (requestCode == AUDIO_REQUEST && null != data) {
    if (requestCode == AUDIO_REQUEST) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            String uriString = uri.toString();
            File myFile = new File(uriString);
            //    String path = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
            String displayName = null;
            String path2 = getAudioPath(uri);
            File f = new File(path2);
            long fileSizeInBytes = f.length();
            long fileSizeInKB = fileSizeInBytes / 1024;
            long fileSizeInMB = fileSizeInKB / 1024;
            if (fileSizeInMB > 8) {
                customAlterDialog("Can't Upload ", "sorry file size is too large");
            }

            else {
                profilePicUrl = path2;
                isPicSelect = true;
                            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            // handle exceptions that may be thrown.
            Toast.makeText(GroupDetailsActivity.this, "Unable to process,try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //   String path1 = uri.getPath();
    
    }
}
```

This helper function is used for retrieving the absolute path of the audio file.

```java
private String getAudioPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] data = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(), uri, data, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: You might want to add some information, not just a block of code.

Comment: function getAudioPath(Uri uri) returns null for me.

Comment: Whether we have to get any permission before launching intent chooser?. I am getting Null pointer exception in this line `val uri: Uri = data?.data!!`. The stacktrace is as follows `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=12, result=0, data=null} to activity`

Answer (score 1):

No need to add type here like audio/*. It will crash to search such type of action.
Try this. It worked for me.

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(intent, AUDIO_REQUEST_CODE)
```

Comment: You are right, adding "audio/*" will crash the app

Answer (score 0):

```
final Uri uri=Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Audio/abc.mp3");
```

Replace `/Audio/abc.mp3` with `your path of mp3 file on sdcard`.

Dont forget to check if the external storage is mounted.
`Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)`

Answer (score 0):

//To pick audio file from device. Place below code in calling activity

```
int REQUEST_CODE = 1001;

 Intent audioIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
 startActivityForResult(audioIntent,REQUEST_CODE);
```

// Override `onActivityForResult` method in activity

```
@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){

  if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK ){

        //the selected audio.Do some thing with uri
        Uri uri = data.getData(); 


  }

  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```