# Why Android media file chooser is canceled?

Tags: android, android-intent, media

I am developing an Android app that has a feature for uploading some music media files to the external server.

To find the media file, I used the below code, which doesn't need any permission:

```kotlin
val targetIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK).apply { 
    type = MediaStore.Images.Media.CONTENT_TYPE
}
val intent = Intent.createChooser(targetIntent, "select music file")
startActivityForResult(intent, reqCode)
```

This code works fine some devices (Samsung Galaxy S series).
But it doesn't work on the Pixel 7 API 33 emulator.

```kotlin
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    // the resultCode is always 0 (RESULT_CANCELED)
}
```

Here is the log:

```
09:36:27.911 ChooserActivity         android           D  ResolveInfo Package is com.google.android.apps.youtube.music
09:36:27.928   ActivityTaskManager     system_server     I  START u0 {act=android.intent.action.PICK typ=vnd.android.cursor.dir/audio flg=0x3000000 cmp=com.google.android.apps.youtube.music/.activities.MusicPickerActivity} from uid 10163
09:36:28.082 MusicPickerActivity     com...tube.music  W  No data URI given to PICK action
```

In the Pixel 7 API 33 emulator, there is a Youtube Music App.
What I expected is the Youtube Music App should be opened to select music files.

In the Samsung Galaxy devices, Music file selector app is opened and it works fine.

What's the problem? and How can I fix it?

Comment: My guess : you are using intent media type images for picking the audio file. You could try using appropriate intent.

Answer (score 0):

My guess :

You are using intent media type images for picking the audio file. You could try using appropriate intent.

This may help

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
startActivityForResult(intent, AUDIO_REQUEST_CODE)
```

Original source :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63556343/2070800